# Passing multiple paramters to web api 2 from angularJs Controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am attempting to call an httpGet on a web api controller from my angular controller but nothing I've been able to do allows me to pass multiple parameters.

I have tried adding the parameters to the route, (`route/{email}/{firstName}/{lastName}`.

I can verify that the angular method, `getCurrentAlumniInfo` is getting called and is attempting to route to a controller. I have used Postman, with the following URI,

```
"localHost: PortNumber/api/alumni/currentAlumniInfo?Email=flintrock&FirstName=Fredf&LastName=Flintstone"
```

Here are the relevant snippets. First, WebApiConfig using attribute routing:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );


            var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        }
    }
```

Next my api controller

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/Alumni")]
 public class AlumniController : ApiController
 { 
        private readonly AlumniRepository _repository;
        private readonly AuthRepository _authRepository;

        public AlumniController()
        {
            _repository = new AlumniRepository();
            _authRepository=new AuthRepository();
        }

        [Route("alumniInfo")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult GetAlumniInfo([FromUri]string email,string firstName, string lasttName)
        {
            return Ok("Success" + lasttName);
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, the angular (v. 1)

```
 var getCurrentAlumniInfo = function() {

            var alumniData = alumniModel.buildAlumniMatchData();
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            //string email, string lastName,string middleName, string firstName
            $http.get(serviceBase + 'api/alumni/alumniInfo',
                {
                    params: {
                        Email: encodeURIComponent(alumniData.email),
                        FirstName: alumniData.firstName,
                        //MiddleName: alumniData.middleName,
                        LastName: alumniData.lastName
                    }
                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    deferred.resolve(response);
                })
                .catch(function(response) {
                    alert(response.statusCode + " error: " + response.status);
                    deferred.reject(response);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

For what it's worth, I'm using v. 4.5.2 of the framework and Visual Studio 2015.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case others land here looking to solve the issue, this won't help them -- unless they too have coded too late at night. The answer is in my code. I typed a parameter string lasttname with two t's. Yes, it was literally that easy and that stupid and I looked at it for an hour without realizing it. It was only seeing the question this morning that it stood out like two t's in 480 pt. font. 
With attribute routing, literally all that is required is that the parameter names match the URI variable names. One could create a model and add the [FromUri] attribute to the parameter, but it isn't necessary in this case.

So, the controller can simply be

```
[Route("alumniInfo")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetAlumniInfo(string email, string firstName, string lastName)
{
    return Ok("Success" + lastName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

either you should change your ***get*** method to ***post*** and pass the parameter as model, so that you can receive the model as parameter of your API.

**Service**

```
$http.post(serviceBase + 'api/alumni/alumniInfo',
            {
                params: {
                    Email: encodeURIComponent(alumniData.email),
                    FirstName: alumniData.firstName,
                    //MiddleName: alumniData.middleName,
                    LastName: alumniData.lastName
                }
            })
            .then(function(response) {
               ...
            })
            .catch(function(response) {
             ...
            });
```

Model

```
 public class RecieveModel
  {
            public string Email  {get;set;}
            public string FirstName {get;set;}
            public string LastName{get;set;}
  }
```

API

```
    [Route("alumniInfo")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAlumniInfo(ReceiveModel model)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

**OR**

change your route config `defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional ,id1 = RouteParameter.Optional,id2 = RouteParameter.Optional}
                );`

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{id1}/{id2}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional ,id1 = RouteParameter.Optional,id2 = RouteParameter.Optional});
```

Comment: Trying very hard to not have map individual routes. I would really prefer to use attribute routing, and I'm not sure why that doesn't work? Your comment to change to a post has crossed my mind, but it seems wrong that I can't do a get, which is, in fact, the correct action to retrieve current data.